# Symbolic Derivates: Why my R code is much faster than my MATLAB code?

Tags: r, matlab, symbolic-math

I coded up in R and MATLAB the symbolic derivative of a simple function, and I computed the value of the derivative at `x = 4`. I repeat the operation 1000 times (because that's what I will need later).

**MATLAB code**

```
tic
for i=1:1000

syms nu;

t=100;
gam=3;
x=4;

myfunction = (-gam * nu) + 0.5 * t * nu *log(nu/2)-t*log(gamma(nu/2));

out = double(subs(diff(myfunction),nu,x));
end
toc
```

**R code**

```
ptm <- proc.time()

for (i in 1:1000) {

t<-100
gam<-3
x<-4

myfunction <- deriv(~(-gam * nu) + 0.5 * t * nu * log(nu/2) - t * 
                  log(gamma(nu/2)), c("nu"), function(nu) {
                  }, hessian = TRUE)

aux1 <- myfunction(x)

out <- attr(aux1, "gradient")[1]

}

proc.time() - ptm
```

When comparing the execution speed of my R and MATLAB codes, R is much faster than MATLAB.

MATLAB code: 28 seconds; R code : 0.18 seconds.

How is it possible? Do I miss something?

Comment: There can be a number of reasons, the underlying structure(s) of the functions. Are they exactly the same? Computational(processor power) might result in different results for different users. Hence one might also state that MATLAB is faster than R on their computer or OS(not sure though).

Comment: I have never used R for symbolic stuff, so I have no idea how fast it is. Certainly MATLAB is not fast  for symbolic maths. The MATrix LABoratory software is fast for matrix and numeric maths.

Comment: I don't know what Matlab does there, but `stats:::deriv.formula` is pretty much completely implemented in C code. You (and I) also haven't checked timings without the JIT compiler.

Comment: This is the symbolic package in Matlab, not Matlab itself, whereas you are using base R so it is not clear that this is a fair comparison.

Comment: Your Matlab example is not a particularly good one. The loop variable is not really used. It doesn't take advantage of any vectorization. Variables are unnecessarily re-declared on every loop iteration (e.g., ```syms nu;```), which is particularly expensive for symbolic variables. A number of optimization might be able to be made, but it's hard to tell without looking at the real case.